# dynamic template variables values based on other template variables in influxdb - chronograf

Tags: influxdb, chronograf, template-variables

I have two template variables and I want that after selecting first template variable from dropdown, second template variable should be dynamic based on first variable value.

let me clear this scenario with an example:
assume I have this data:

**data=>** System=10 
**tags=>** appName="a", appVersion="1.1"

**data=>** System=12 
**tags=>** appName="b", appVersion="2.1"

I have defined two template variables **:appName:** and **:appVersion:**
and Im getting their values using this meta query

`SHOW TAG VALUES ON "db_name" FROM "measurement_name" WITH KEY = appName`
`SHOW TAG VALUES ON "db_name" FROM "measurement_name" WITH KEY = appVersion`

now whenever I select :appName: = 'a', I want that :appVersion: should show only "1.1" value in dropdown. But :appVersion: shows both values "1.1" and "2.1". We know "2.1" value is useless when we have selected appName=a.

I thought I can use this for defining :appVersion: 
`SHOW TAG VALUES ON "db_name" FROM "measurement_name" WITH KEY = appVersion WHERE appName = :appName:`
but this is not working

Please help me to achieve this kind of dynamic/codependent variables in chronograf

Answer (score 0):

solved this with this:

```
show tag values on "db_name" from "measurement_name" with key = "appVersion" where appName = ':app_name:'
```

I had to use single quote after where clause. Seems I cant use " here